# PLCrashReporter doesnt open when the app crashes

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, crash-reports, plcrashreporter

first time user of PLCrashReporter. I have written the code in my appDelegate.m file

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{       
NSLog(@"inside applicationdidfinishlaunching to do crash reporting");
PLCrashReporter *crashReporter = [PLCrashReporter sharedReporter];
NSError *error;

if ([crashReporter hasPendingCrashReport])
    [self handleCrashReport];

if (![crashReporter enableCrashReporterAndReturnError:&error])
    NSLog(@"Warning: Could not enable crash reporter %@",error);
```

}

I wrote handleCrashReport as it is in the example. I also on purpose crashed my app on clicking a button.(NSRangeException  index 0 beyond bounds for empty array) like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *mtestArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSLog(@"%@",[mtestArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

It throws exception (i.e. goes to main.m file. Doesn't go to home screen. It stays on the main.m file). I stop the execution and restart the app and it goes to a screen (this screen occurs if it were correct actually). I dont see a pop up saying send crash report or don't. I added CrashReporter.framework and libcrashreporter-iphonesimulator.a to my project. I changed mach-o and perfom single...as told in the article. I have been at this for more than 2 hours. Why dont i see the error dialog?

I put breakpoints at my applicationdidfinishlaunching and they NEVER get hit. I deleted my app and reinstalled (re-run) and still no go. Also my project is an iPad project with iOS 6.1. I read that crash report dialog appears on second time start of the app. But it won't any time,2nd or 3rd. If you need more information, please ask. Thanks
EDIT : Does plcrash reporter work for iPads also? I took the help from this blogpost 
http://mandeepdhiman.blogspot.com/2011/10/crash-reporter-for-ios.html

Comment: What do you mean by "I put breakpoints at my applicationDidFinishLaunching and they NEVER get hit"? Do you mean that applicationDidFinishLaunching is not being executed, or do you mean that hasPendingCrashReport is called but never returns TRUE?

Comment: @puzzle. You see the NSLog statement there right? That is not getting logged. I mean my app does not even enter that method. If it had logged then i would know if it entered or did not enter handleCrashReport. But i got stopped, as it is not even entering and logging that line.

Comment: Have you tried using `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` instead? The method `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` is fairly antiquated, from iOS 3.0 and later you should use `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions`.

Comment: @puzzle. I found out another way to do this. I came across HockeyApp. It worked for me. Thanks again for your time.