# Sending ios crash reports to developers from users

Tags: ios, ipad, licensing, client, plcrashreporter

I am developing an in-house ipad app. I gave it to the client for testing.
The app crashes sometimes on his iPad.

How can i get his crash report to me?

On my testing ipad i go to *Xcode->Organizer* and i have device logs. People suggested i could use **PLCrashReporter**. So i started to use it. Can I use it?

Or are there any licensing issues? For testing on my device i tried to use **PLcrashreporter**. It is giving me issues. 
Here is the link for my other question.
[PLCrashReporter doesnt open when the app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970771/plcrashreporter-doesnt-open-when-the-app-crashes)

Or should i abandon this and try for another way to get the crash report from the client? If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hockey App is also a great alternative for this.  They have a very nice UI and it easily supports both ad hoc, in house, and App Store distributions.

It will also automatically sybmolicate the crash reports on the server if you upload the .dsym along with the binary.

You then get daily/weekly reports and on demand access via the website to crash data.

http://www.hockeyapp.net

Comment: Thanks. So i was going through the site. On the dashboard i came across "start integration". So it asked for my CFBundleIdentifier and all that. So i am worried about licensing. Do they get any hold of my app/code?A novice iOS programmer here. Please help thanks.

Comment: No, there won't be any issues. To get crash reports the service needs some identification data of your app so it can assign the incoming reports to your app. You need to upload the dSYM of your app, so the crash reports get symbolicated. None of all this will have any effect on your code or licenses. There is nothing to fear in that regard. You can check the terms of service and privacy policies on the bottom of the page for more legal information.

Comment: @Kerni.Thanks for clearing that. Yes i went to the discussion board on HockeyApp and had good discussion. They cleared my doubts. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

TestFlight will log crash reports for you automatically. You just need to add a little code to your project. It might be more work than you'd like to go through now because you'll have to integrate your app and users into the TestFlight pipeline, but it automates much of what you want here. It's also still free (as far as I know). We've found it really helpful.

https://www.testflightapp.com

SDK:

https://www.testflightapp.com/sdk/download/

Comment: Thanks. So is TestFlight just for testing/testers? What if tomorrow i will want to deploy the app and the app crashes while the actual end user is using it. How can client send me his crash report? Can i still use TestFlight in that case?

Comment: Yes, TestFlight says they support apps in production in the App Store: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/829571-does-the-sdk-support-production-builds-

Answer (score 0):

Testflight is pretty good for this kind of stuff.

Testflight allows you to 'test flight' your app out to the testers -

- you can upload your test version to testflight
- testflight will notify your testers via email
- allows them to download and install from the email
- will record crashes, and will symbolicate them if you upload the dsym file.

https://testflightapp.com/

You'll have to register your testers devices and it's a little complex to setup up (but nor more so than any other 3rd party sdk) though it won't catch certain crashes though like when the OS kills it.

Comment: Thanks. From what you are saying it is for testing only SDK.  I want it in the actual app. Like tomorrow if the actual end user is using my app. If it crashes then, can user send me a crash report using this TestFlight.